# Resizing the form when the Language changes

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

C# WinForms: Imagine there are a bunch of controls inside the red and yellow panels.  Actually they do not need to be panels. Whatever you suggest is Ok.
Functionality Required: when it is English language resizing is Ok because the form just looks like what I had designed in designer. when the language changes there the issue appears because the label gets a very longer text in translated mode and it just does not fit it the yellow are.
So: (1) I want some UI design idea that when the label needs more room, it auto resizes and the yellow area resizes and pushes the Red area to the right and also the form will resize of course to show everything. 
2) I want the Red area to grow if I resize the form so I can do this by Anchoring the red area to the right, fine...BUT I do Not want the Yellow area to resize if I resize the Form. I only want it resize when the contents inside it need more room. 
3) I may be wrong be I used a TableLayout with two columns for red and yellow areas  and put the columns on AutoSize mode but it did not fix the issue....

what do you suggest?

[image]

Comment: Use WPF instead.  ;-)  It can handle much of this for you.

Comment: WPF is not a choice for me. I have to use Win32 Forms.

Comment: A TableLayoutPanel should work. Maybe you used it wrong.

Comment: Then what wrong did I make? I described what I did with table layout .. red in one column, yellow in another column, set both columns on auto-resize mode.

Comment: The Size and Location properties are localized.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to make a class that inherits the System.Forms.Controls.Button or Label class. Override the TextChanged event, then in your Paint function, use MeasureFont to measure the size of the text and change the size of the button accodingly. So something like this:

```
public class MyButton : Button 
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;

        SizeF stringSize = g.MeasureFont(this.Text, this.Font);

        this.Resize(SizeF.Width + 10, SizeF.Height + 10);
     }
}
```

Something along those lines. I have not tested this.